# JSF autoassign value to a bean property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What can I use to autoassign a fixed value to a bean property in my view? I use the following component to submit the form:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myDetailController.create}" ... />
```

So everything is working and the form gets submitted. I want to automatically assign the value of `1` to `myDetailController.selected.number`. It must always be `1` everytime the link is clicked. Is this anyway possible without using `onClick=""` in `<h:сommandLink>`? If not, can you specify how to fire more than one action in `UICommand` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to nest a `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside your `<h:commandLink>`:

```
<h:commandLink ... >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="1" target="#{myDetailController.selected.number}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The other possibility is to add a line to your action method `myDetailController.create`:

```
selected.setNumber(1);
```

You can otherwise specify as many action listeners to your `<h:commandLink>` as you wish by nesting additional `<f:actionListener>` tags, remembering that there is also a place for specifying one action listener in a `actionListener` attribute of `<h:commandLink>`.

---

After rereading your question it seems that you fail to understand what you ultimately want. You need something different than a fixed `1`: you need to set the property to `1` only in case the command link in question was clicked and to `0` in other conditions. This way you can distinguish if the command component in question has been triggered. This is done in a different manner: you firstly need to check if client id of the command link in question is present in the request parameter map and only then take the decision what value to put in. So, basically, your requirements can be met by a following line(s) in your view:

```
<h:commandLink ... >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{empty param[component.clientId] ? 0 : 1}" 
                                 target="#{myDetailController.selected.number}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

or in your action method:

```
selected.setNumber(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().
                           containsKey("formId:commandLinkId" ? 1 : 0);
```